# showing error(symbols that are difficult to comprehend) while downloading pdf file

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

i have a writte a code for downloading pdf file. It is properly working on localhost but i m getting error while running these code on godaddy where i am hosting.
here is the code

```
    <?php
    include "connect.inc.php";
    if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $query = "select filename from pdf where id=$id";
    $row = mysql_query($query);
    if(mysql_num_rows($row)==1){
      $query_row=mysql_fetch_assoc($row);
      $name=$query_row['filename'];
      $path="upload/{$name}";


    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$name}");
    header('Content-Length: '. filesize($path));
    readfile($path);



    }
    }
    ?>
```

Output:
%PDF-1.4 %âãÏÓ 670 0 obj <> endobj xref 670 7 0000000016 00000 n 0000000912 00000 n 0000000977 00000 n 0000001122 00000 n 0000001188 00000 n 0000001305 00000 n 0000000436 00000 n trailer <<97ED15AB8479334F8971D1FF246DC63D>]>> ...

Answer (score 0):

You have two `Content-Type` headers. Make up your mind.

Comment: True that, but shouldn't the second header replace the first by default?

Comment: thnx Ignacio but without using second header these code would not be able to download pdfs.... bdw its working now